# Force Firefox to drop SQLite lock from cookies.sqlite

Tags: firefox, sqlite, cookies

I'd like to delete certain Firefox cookie. The problem is I'd like to do it when Firefox is open. When I try to access the cookies.sqlite I get the database is locked error. Is there any way I can force Firefox to drop the lock without closing firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Not that it matters since just deleting it out of the database will not change the program's run-time behavior (short of causing logic errors upon update perhaps) since all cookies are stored in a hash table.  The database is just to keep cookies across sessions.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix (that should include MacOSX, Linux, BSD, ...), you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME=/tmp/cookies.$$
cp $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite $NAME
sqlite $NAME 'Play your perverse games with the data here.'
cp $NAME $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/cookies.sqlite
rm $NAME
```

Although as sdwilsh has mentioned this will probably not achieve what you want, but the above
pattern is at least useful for extracting data from the sqlite databases that firefox uses.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it using `sqlite manager` extension for firefox?